# How to call a validation callback function within formValidation plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, callback

I'm using the formValidation plugin from http://formvalidation.io/examples/ in a HTML5 form to perform validation on the form inputs.

The standard checks such as `notEmpty` work as expected on the input. But now I have a case where the input needs to validated against a list. I've already coded the function `checkEMIDExists()` to do that but haven't figured out how to call it from within the formValidation plugin.

[This is the example I've followed](http://formvalidation.io/validators/callback/) in order to try an implement the callback function. But during run-time the call back function doesn't fire when filling out the `EM` input value.

I've set an alert within the callback that *does* trigger every time I change input value. I also verified that `checkEMIDExists()` works by triggering it on the `change` event and it does work.

It seems that the way I'm returning the bool validation result isn't correct.

**Question:**

How can I call a callback function within formValidation plugin?

Code: (gist)

**EM input element -**

```
  <input id="EscID" name="EM" maxlength="10" type="text" data-error="EM already exists or none supplied" placeholder="(If Applicable)" class="form-control">
```

**Script -**

```
<script>

    //List EM input is validated against
    var escHistoryList = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.EscHistory));


    $(document).ready(function () {


        var $createForm = $('#createForm');


        //Validate the required input fields to prevent submit if not 
        //valid input.
        $('#createForm').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: 
                Application: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The Application name field is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                EM: {
                    validators: {
                        callback: {
                            message: 'A record with this EPRID already exists!',
                            callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                                // Determine if the input EPRID already exists
                                var emidVal = $('#EscalationID').val();
                                alert("IN VALIDATOR CALLBACK");
                                var isEMIDMatch = false;

                                isEMIDMatch = checkEMIDExists(emidVal);

                                if(isEMIDMatch)
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }


        });



        //Determineif input EMID exists in list
        function checkEMIDExists(emidVal){

            var isMatch = false;
            for(var i=0;i<escHistoryList.length;i++){
                if(escHistoryList[i]["EM"].indexOf(emidVal) > -1){
                    isMatch = true;
                    break;
                }

            }

            return isMatch;
        }









    });//end $(document).ready


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback method should also return false in case the validation fails. 
A null return value is ignored.

Change your callback return statement to:

```
return isEMIDMatch;
```

or perhaps even more succinctly albeit less readable:

```
return checkEMIDExists(emidVal);
```